# Opposite of the welfare state?

Tags: terminology

We use the term "Welfare state" to describe states that feel responsible to provide its citizens with minimal means allowing to live with dignity, like the education for children, healthcare, housing etc.

Is there a term for the opposite of the welfare state? Which means, a state, that not necessarily wants to make the lives of its citizens as miserable of possible, but simply doesn't care if people have no means to provide their children necessary education, or if they are left without money after retirement.

Comment: There are multiple century long periods in which "simply doesn't care" would have been the best deal people could have imagined getting from their govts.  The 20th century for example.

Comment: "business friendly government" is a common euphemism in support of the concept, "neoliberal paradise" is a common one opposed to it. That's a bit sarcastic and polemical though. Something along the lines of "liberalized business policy" would paint the picture in a fairly neutral way. The "night watchman" answer below is of course the purist example, but in practice, the real-world "anti-welfare" position does still include regulations for smooth handling of contracts and contract disputes, and a certain amount of taxation so as to provide infrastructure.

Answer (score 7):

I think the term you are looking for is "night-watchman state". A state where the government's sole function is to provide internal and external security against violence in the form of police, military and courts.

Answer (score 3):

"The opposite of welfare state" and "a state that simply doesn't care if people have no means to provide their children necessary education, or if they are left without money after retirement" are not necessarily the same thing. There are some terms we can apply here, though.

**Ambivalent State**
An ambivalent state is corrupt. Essentially, it involves people with power (police, politicians etc.) in collusion with crime syndicates to advance their own interests. In this case, they do not care about education but largely because they are interested in their own survival. They only mess with citizens when it is in their interest to do so.

**Weak State**
Weak states are states that largely defer to private industry on policy decisions. They care about education and pension insofar as industry cares about it. Because industry would rather not have to pay to educate and pension their labour, it is rare that a weak state will not care about education and pensions.

If you are thinking about the United States, you may want to consider...

**Calvinist State** Calvinism has been famously explored by Max Weber (The Protestant Ethic) as a reason for the success of the United States despite that religious states in general have tended to fail under capitalism. Pure Calvinists believe(d) that success and sin is predetermined. Thus, education and pensions are things that god's chosen people will pursue themselves because they are not sinners. Now, I'm not sure how many Americans are pure Calvinists anymore. I imagine it's not very many. However, that Calvinist influence can still be seen in many of its institutions.

**Night-watchman or Minarchist State** Minarchism is a compromise by some libertarians who recognize that anarchy cannot be maintained without some state presence. In general, this is a theoretical state rather one that actually exists. The closest we get are early capitalist states which are more commonly described as classic liberal states, which rather quickly evolved (or devolved) into institution-making states. I should add that Minarchist states would likely evolve (or devolve) to include some welfare because the evidence on government spending for health and educations is just too strong. The multiplier effect on education and health can be very high, often greater than 1000% in returns to GDP for dollar spent. The most anti-state person would eventually have to concede at least some spending is useful.

I guess I'm ultimately saying that the economics on "an opposite of a welfare state" works against its existing in the real world. This should be obvious just by looking at the global environment. States that spend nothing on education are a mess. At the end of the day, it would be impossible for even the most libertarian taxpayer to ignore the 10+ fold ROI on their tax dollars.

This does not mean that the current welfare state is the correct answer either. You cannot theorize a state into working. Not even with a huge army of believers. States form over time based on beliefs, traditions, habits, learning from mistakes and growth of the population. The so-called "Welfare state" is not a thing, but a name we gave to how people thought about what would make us prosperous after World War II.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with *[Laissez-Faire](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/laissezfaire.asp) state*.  It's not a perfect match, by any means, being more geared to deregulation than concerned with non-welfare, but note the opposition between Hoover and Roosevelt on the subject of welfare.  As a term, it has some traction on Google's [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=laissez-faire%20state&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Claissez%20-%20faire%20state%3B%2Cc0).

Face it, in a democracy, no politician is going to campaign on the "no help for the poor" platform posited in the question. Not while something along the line of [trickle down theory](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/trickledowntheory.asp) can be marketed instead.

> Laissez-faire is an economic theory from the 18th century that opposed any government intervention in business affairs. The driving principle behind laissez-faire, a French term that translates to "leave alone" (literally, "let you do"), is that the less the government is involved in the economy, the better off business will be, and by extension, society as a whole. Laissez-faire economics is a key part of free-market capitalism.
>
> Later free-market economists built on the ideas of laissez-faire as a path to economic prosperity, though detractors have **criticized it for promoting inequality.**

While Laissez Faire is mostly associated with non-regulation, the express intent to limit taxation and the additional stricture to [minimize government roles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laissez-faire) are somewhat of a match.

> Since, in their view, this natural order functioned successfully without the aid of government, they advised the state **to restrict itself to upholding the rights of private property and individual liberty**, to removing all artificial barriers to trade, and to abolishing all useless laws".

For example, with [Hoover](https://www.thebalance.com/president-hoovers-economic-policies-4583019), president at the start of 1929 Great Depression:

> Hoover was an advocate of **laissez-faire** economics. He believed an economy based on capitalism would self-correct. **He felt that economic assistance would make people stop working.** He believed business prosperity would trickle down to the average person. This philosophy was not effective against the Depression. His failure to end it led to his defeat in the 1932 presidential election against **Franklin D. Roosevelt and his New Deal.**

The New Deal and Roosevelt are ancestors to the Keynesian economics that led to welfare states, so they seem in opposition to Hoover and his Laissez Faire.

p.s. I am just answering the question, not taking sides.  Both approaches have their place, in moderation.  Both will be sub-optimal, in excess.